# Best practices for MySQL queries in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm pretty new to nodeJS, and what's the best way to implement SQL queries..

When I'm doing a mysql insert in NodeJS I need to query to see if the value exists, then I need to do an additional query to grab the max value of 1 field.

Everything has call-backs, and relies on one query to execute before moving on to the next.
This is getting pretty messy, especially because I have to pass all the callbacks in the functions.

I'm considering creating stored procedures to keep the logic cleaner..

```
this.get = function(data, callback, getMaxOrder, parentScope){
    var val = db.query('select * from my_table where ?', data, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        callback(data, result, getMaxOrder, parentScope);
    });
}

this.getMaxOrder = function(data, callback, parentScope){
    var val = db.query('select max(`order`) as maxOrder from my_table where some_attr = ?', [data.some_attr], function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        callback(data, result, parentScope);
    });
}

this.parentInsert = function(data, callback){
    console.log("call parent insert..");
    db.config.queryFormat = db.config.defaultQueryFormat;
    db.query('insert into cards SET ?', data, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //callback(result);
    });     
}

this.insert = function(data, callback){
    //get all names w/ the same board id..

    var getResults = function(data, results, getMaxOrder, parentScope){
        if(results.length == 0){
            console.log("incremenet the order..");
            //by getting... max order..

            var maxOrderCallback = function (data, results, parentScope){
                var order = results[0].maxOrder + 1;
                //now update...                 


                var newData = {order: order, name: data.name, boardId: data.boardId, userId: data.userId};
                parentScope(newData);
            }



            getMaxOrder(data, maxOrderCallback, parentScope);
        }else{
            //throw "Name for card in the board already taken!";
        }
    }

    this.get(data, getResults, this.getMaxOrder, this.parentInsert);
 }
```

Comment: Look into promises and async libraries like `async`, `Q`, etc. They facilitate the simultaneous execution of queries with a callback once they all finish, among other cool things.

Comment: `if (err) throw err;` never do this, the correct way to handle error in functions where there is nothing to do is to propagate it up to the caller e.g. `if (err) return callback(err)`. Eventually it will reach the UI layer where you can say that an error happened. What you are doing now is crashing the web-server whenever there is a hiccup in the MySQL server. If this happens for 1% of queries then if you get 100 users, your server is constantly crashing.

Comment: That said callbacks or callback libraries cannot abstract away manual propagation of errors and forgetting to propagate an error is a devastating bug. Promises or anything that automates this is a must. Remember that you are not even doing resource management, making sure that every callback path closes resource even when it fails is pure madness. Using one global db connection isn't really a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic case of [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/). See if your mysql driver supports [Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/). If not, there are some query generators that do:

- https://github.com/doxout/anydb-sql
- http://knexjs.org/